# Ember v2 how to handle nested models and computed properties that rely on controller property

Tags: ember.js

I'm using Ember/Ember-Data v.2.1.0 to develop an analytics webapp, and new to both...

My route loads a model 'parent' which has a hasMany relationship with another model 'child', each of which has several belongsTo relationships with a third model 'grandchild'. It is not unusual for a parent to have a dozen children, each of which has a dozen children, each of which displayed in the template and consumed by data-oriented components.

One of the properties on 'grandchild' is a hash with key/value pairs.

```
ratings: DS.attr()
```

Which in the database is...

```
{ 'r1': 10, 'r2': 30, 'r3': 35... }
```

Another property on 'grandchild' is a computed property that returns a specific value in the hash, and a third property which does some math...

```
rating: Ember.computed('ratings', 'rSample', function() {
  return this.get(`ratings.${this.get('rSample')}`);
},
cost: DS.attr(number),
value: Ember.computed('rating', 'cost', function() {
 return this.get('rating') / this.get('cost');
}
```

This works; however, what I want is to have 'rSample' as a value on the route's controller.

To goal is to have a component in the route's template that allows the user to set the value of 'rSample', which will be consistent across all 'grandchild' records displayed in the template and used in the analytics components.

Since none of these computed properties is ever saved to the database, I'm not sure the model is even the correct place for these computed properties. And having a model be aware of a controller seems like an anti-pattern.

But I have no idea how to set computed properties for the grandchildren on the controller, since the route is loading the 'grandparent' model.

What I've done for now is set variables in the model...

```
rSample: 'r50'
```

And then set an observer in the controller to watch for changes and update...

```
rSample: '50',
rSampleChanged: Ember.observer('rSample', 'players.[]', function() {
    this.get('players').forEach((player) => {
        player.set('rSample', `r${this.get('rSample')}`);
    });
})
```

But there's probably a much better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would approach this would be to use is to have a component that handles user changes to the rSample value, then propagate those changes down to the child components. In the child components, you could do the same computed actions as before.

For the parent component definition:

```
{{parent-component grandChildModels=grandChildModels}}
```

In the parent component template:

```
{{input value=rSample}}

{{#each grandChildModel as |model|}}
  {{child-component rSample=rSample model=model}}
{{/each}}
```

Then in the child component you can use some of the computed's that you were using.

Downsides of this approach is that the parent component and child component are very intertwined, pretty inflexible. On the plus side you can easily pass the rSample value to the grand child models without relying on observers and not polluting the controller with the rSample logic.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my case, I need a parent component maintaining some state among child components dealing with data manipulation anyways, which is what I'm using the route's controller for. However, with the push away from controllers to components, I think your solution is more elegant. I'm going to mark it as answered.